# Overblown balloon: explode or burst?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

I want to describe how to blow and explode a balloon so do  we say balloon will explode or burst if you over blow it?
Which describe it better: "explode" or "burst"?
I checked online some sources say we can say "blow out" for both entering air to balloon or exploding it.

Comment: Normal balloons pop or burst. [Here's a video of *exploding* balloons.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ce6imsXTkGQ)

Answer (score 9):

*Blew out* is understandable, but I don't think it's common. In my experience, the only thing I can think of that blows out (in the sense of "exploding") is a tire.

> My tire blew out!

Between *explode* and *burst*, I think *burst* is better suited. *Explode* is more often used when the "explosion" was very violent, and it is especially apt when it was chemically induced.

You can also say that it *popped*. In my opinion, *pop* is softest, while *explode* is least soft (not soft at all): *pop < burst < explode*.

I provide relevant definitions and an Ngram search below.

> - [burst](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/burst) verb (used without object), burst or, often bursted, bursting.
>
>   1. to break, break open, or fly apart with sudden violence:
>        The bitter cold caused the pipes to burst.
> - [pop](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pop)   verb (used without object), popped, popping.
>
>   2. to burst open with such a sound, as chestnuts or corn in roasting.
> - [explode](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/explode?s=t)  verb (used without object), exploded, exploding.
>
>   2. to burst, fly into pieces, or break up violently with a loud report, as a boiler from excessive pressure of steam.
>
> (Dictionary.com)

I redid the search with "balloon will pop" vs "balloon will explode" vs "balloon will burst" to try to better match the OP's "balloon will ____". [Here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=balloon+will+pop%2C+balloon+will+explode%2C+balloon+will+burst&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cballoon%20will%20pop%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cballoon%20will%20burst%3B%2Cc0) are the results:
[image]
Notice that "balloon will explode" does not map. Between *pop* and *burst*, I think they're equally acceptable, with the slight distinction I made above.

Comment: Thanks for prodding me into ngram research on this one; it seems the picture is not quite as simple as suggested, but my answer wasn't complete either.

Comment: Yeah, it's tricky. I tried to rephrase mine to keep it simple, but there is more that can be analyzed.

Answer (score 6):

The most common word for a balloon disintegrating on purpose is *popping*, because it's a sudden but fairly small event. *Bursting* is also acceptable, and is slightly more common when there's no deliberate attempt. (See frequencies below from [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=balloon+_VERB_+explode%2Cballoon+_VERB_+burst%2Cballoon+_VERB_+pop_INF%2Cpop+_DET_+balloon%2Cexplode+_DET_+balloon%2Cburst+_DET_+balloon&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cballoon%20_VERB_%20explode%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cballoon%20_VERB_%20burst%3B%2Cc0%3B.t3%3B%2Cballoon%20_VERB_%20pop_INF%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bballoon%20_VERB_%20popped%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bballoon%20_VERB_%20pop%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpop%20_DET_%20balloon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexplode%20_DET_%20balloon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cburst%20_DET_%20balloon%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cballoon%20_VERB_%20explode%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cballoon%20_VERB_%20burst%3B%2Cc0%3B.t3%3B%2Cballoon%20_VERB_%20pop_INF%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Bballoon%20_VERB_%20popped%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bballoon%20_VERB_%20pop%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpop%20_DET_%20balloon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexplode%20_DET_%20balloon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cburst%20_DET_%20balloon%3B%2Cc0).    `_DET_` means articles like *a* and *the*, and I used it for cases like "he popped the balloon"; `_VERB_` means verbs like *will*, *did*, etc, most of which fit cases like "and then the balloon burst".)

[image]

*Exploding* is too strong a word. *Blowing out* could theoretically be used, but it's usually used in cases where there's no confusion, and especially when the failure occurs in only one direction instead of all directions at once (for example, a seal on a pipe can "blow out", sending whatever's inside out in a jet).

Answer (score 3):

You can't really use [overblown](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/overblown), because it has another meaning: **bigger or more important or impressive than it should be**.

According to the [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/overinflated) (see meaning 2), overinflated would work as an adjective. If you want a verb, you can use over-inflate: it's not really a standard word, so you should really use a hyphen.

> If you over-inflate a balloon, it will burst.

Answer (score 1):

You could say either

> Inflate the ballon until it **explodes**.
>   Inflate the balloon until it **bursts**.

and both sentences would be understood with the same meaning.

When a balloon *bursts* it creates an *explosive* sound.

However, the word you are looking for is

> burst

especially since you making the balloon fail by purposely increases the *internal* air pressure.

If there is too much rain water buildup

> a dam will **burst** open

Container boxes have

> **burst** ratings

to describe the amount of internal pressure they can take before failing.

Answer (score 1):

To my mind, I would use burst if the balloon failed while inflating. Popped would be once the balloon has been inflated and tied off. Another way to think of it in my mind is burst is accidental, while popping is more a purposeful action.